# Providing the function value when using Laravel routes 'uses'

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

Normally just pass the uses method to the URL but now need to provide a value for the function.

So I have a ajax call that needs to use the function:

```
public function getPostData($id) {
}
```

Which is in my PostController.

In the past my routes for this would be e.g.:

```
Route::post('createpostaction', array('uses' => 'PostController@create'));
```

How do I now pass a variable into the function?

```
Route::post('getPostData', array('uses' => 'PostController@getPostData));
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Route parameters**](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-parameters) will automatically get passed to the `uses` function.

```
Route::post('get-post-data/{id}', array('uses' => 'PostController@getPostData'));
```

This means that you now have to call the URL like this:

```
get-post-data/123
```

And the controller will receive `123` as the first parameter.

If you add a second route parameter

```
Route::post('get-post-data/{id}/{foo}', array('uses' => 'PostController@getPostData'));
```

You receive it as second parameter

```
public function getPostData($id, $foo){}
```

and so on...

**Note** The names of route parameters and function arguments don't have to match. Only the order of them is important.